# for-loop in JsFiddle and Codesandbox returns different results. (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

I wrote a simple for-loop using Vue.js. However, the values ​​displayed in Codesandbox and Fiddle are different.

First, you can open [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-data-object-properties-always-return-the-last-value-during-the-for-loop-eo6tz?file=/src/App.vue) to test.

When the 'click me!' button is pressed, the console displays

```
{name: 15} "name: 5"
{name: 15} "name: 10"
{name: 15} "name: 15"
```

At the same time, I also tried similar code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coleon1992/buv6s90m/7/), and the console showed is was what I expected.

```
{name:5}" name:5"
{name:10}" name:10"
{name: 15} "Name: 15"
```

[image]

Why does this happen and how to make the output of Codesandbox the same as JSfiddle?

Comment: in codesandbox you can make the log `JSON.stringify(this.newTask)` as the first statement and then the output will look correct. Can you explain what you are trying to do as console.log is not necessarily the best method to debug? (And your const line can be `const newVal = step` no need for `+0`)

Comment: codesandbox console seems to delayed by setTimeout see [issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1043)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because You changed only `name` property of `object`.
You must change full `object`. Else `object` will take **last value** of name.
try like this:

```
getTask() {
  for (let step = 5; step < 20; step += 5) {
    const newVal = +0 + step;
    this.newTask = {
      name: newVal,
    };
    console.log(this.newTask, "name: " + this.newTask.name);
  }
},
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-data-object-properties-always-return-the-last-value-during-the-for-loop-forked-k1gxn?file=/src/App.vue:0-37)

Answer (score 0):

So the same thing actually happens in both. If you open the actual console (F12 on windows) the output will be `{name: 15}` followed by the string for each log. Jsfiddle has some workaround and if you want to see similar results in codesandbox use `JSON.stringify(this.newTask)`